# How can I invite a peer to a session using a different name from the one that I found the peer with?

Tags: swift, macos, multipeer-connectivity

I am using the Multipeer Connectivity Framework on macOS, and I am trying to implement the functionality of connecting to other peers. I used a `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and displayed the found peers in an `NSTableView`. I also have a `NSTextField` for people to enter their display name, which will be the display name of their `MCPeerID`.

The workflow is as follows: The user enter a display name, selects a peer from the `NSTableView`, and press the connect button.

[image]

This means that I don't have an `MCPeerID` until the connect button is pressed, because before that time the textfield text could still change. However, initialising a `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` requires an `MCPeerID`, so I thought I could use a dummy peer ID for the browser, then create the real one when the connect button is pressed, like this:

```
let dummyPeerID = MCPeerID(displayName: "Unnamed")
override func viewDidLoad() {
    browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: dummyPeerID, serviceType: "some identifier")
    ...
}

@IBAction func connect(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: displayNameTextField.stringValue)
    session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
    session.delegate = self
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
    // selectedTeacher is an RxSwift.Variable<MCPeerID?> that is bound to the selected model object of the table view
    browser.invitePeer(selectedTeacher.value!, to: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 10)
}
```

When I run this code, I saw that `session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState)` is called with a `state` of `.notConnected`, and this is printed in the console:

> Wrong connection data. Participant ID from remote connection data = 7008A6B3, local participant ID = 4F1F9C8D.

I suppose that it means I can't use different `MCPeerID`s for the browser and the session. If I change this line:

```
session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
```

to:

```
session = MCSession(peer: dummyPeerID)
```

Then it is connected to the session correctly.

---

What can I do in this situation, where I don't know the display name of the local peer when browsing for other peers? (Let's assume we can't change the UI design)

Comment: Why not do something like `if displayNameTextField.stringValue.isEmpty { peerID = dummyPeerID }`...

Comment: @l'L'l Can you explain how would that solve the problem? I have my own validation check for when the textfield is empty. I simply disable the connect button. I think my problem is that the peerID used to initialise the browser must be the same as the one used to create the session, but at the time of creating the browser, I don't have the peerID that I would use to create the session, because the user hasn't entered his display name yet.

Comment: Well, [from the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcpeerid/1407077-displayname) it says "For the local peer, you set this property when the object is initialized. It cannot be changed.
For other peer objects provided to you by the framework, this property is provided by the peer and cannot be changed.", so I think you've got a sort of catch 22 here.

Comment: @l'L'l Yeah, I know it's something like that. I was hoping that someone would think of a clever trick or something... or even using private APIs. It's fine if the App Store rejects the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two solutions: using data contexts or using a second browser

**Using data contexts**

Use your dummy id but don't rely on its displayName property. Instead pass your real display name via the context parameter of [`invitePeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID, to session: MCSession, withContext context: Data?, timeout: TimeInterval)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcnearbyservicebrowser/1406944-invitepeer)

```
@IBAction func connect(_ sender: NSButton) {
    session = MCSession(peer: dummyPeerID)
    session.delegate = self
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimation(nil)

    browser.invitePeer(
      selectedTeacher.value!,
      to: session,
      withContext: displayNameTextField.stringValue.data(using: .utf8)!,
      timeout: 10
    )
}
```

---

**Using a second browser**

Create a new MCPeerID and create a second browser with your new `MCPeerID`. Wait until the selectedTeacher is discovered again using your second browser and then use that browser with the new ID to invite the selectedTeacher.

```
var dummyBrowser: InvitingBrowser?
@IBAction func connect(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: displayNameTextField.stringValue)
    session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
    session.delegate = self
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimation(nil)
    // selectedTeacher is an RxSwift.Variable<MCPeerID?> that is bound to the selected model object of the table view
    dummyBrowser = InvitingBrowser(
      session: session,
      serviceType: mcService,
      remote: selectedTeacher.value!
    )
}

class InvitingBrowser: NSObject, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate {
    let browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser
    var remote: MCPeerID
    let session: MCSession

    init(session: MCSession, serviceType: String, remote: MCPeerID) {
        browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: session.myPeerID, serviceType: serviceType)
        self.remote = remote
        self.session = session
        super.init()
        browser.delegate = self
        browser.startBrowsingForPeers()
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
        if peerID == remote {
            browser.invitePeer(peerID, to: session, withContext: nil, timeout: 30)
            browser.stopBrowsingForPeers()
        }
    }

    func browser(_ browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {}
}
```